# How to add dynamic subdomain to site test.mysite.com

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have requirement to manage dynamic subdomains for site like test.mysite.com
BTW my current IIS has already multiple site hosted and each has SSL certificate configured.
What I want to achieve is any subdomain should use the same site.
like profile1.test.mysite.com,profile2.test.mysite.com etc., should use test.mysite.com.
I have added code in site to check the domain URL and based on the first subdomain it set particular profile.
[Here is the binding of one site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgCpQ.png)

Comment: The term you'll want is "wildcard". https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support

Comment: How can I set it with SSL certificate?

Comment: There are wildcard SSL certificates on shelf you can buy from CA.